What my route have to return for the ajax call getImageUrl for the Syncfusion FileManager
My problem is that the File Manager library of Syncfusion doesn't display the pictures.
I configured "ajaxSettings" and "getImageUrl". The ajax call is executed but I still have no picture.
I don't know what my route has to return in order to work? The SyncFusion documentation does not explain exactly what is required.
I use the JavaScript library with a PHP backend.
Here is my JavaScript:
var filemanagerInstance = new ej.filemanager.FileManager({
    ajaxSettings: {
        url: 'http://localhost/index.php?page=getFilesProject&id_projet=' + idProjet,
        getImageUrl: 'http://localhost/index.php?page=getImage',
    },
});

I tried to return a HTML element, e.g.: <img src="$my_path"/>.
I also tried to return the path of the picture, but the library still doesn't show the picture.
The library sends a GET request with these params:
page: getImage path: Documents/Projets/9/ 
id: ../Documents/Projets/9/d9fwkjz-ef8e1e85-62b4-445d-8853-9815b3e5e0d5_66db087cb691e.png time: 1725975676748


I don't know what my route have to return...does the syncfusion documentation not tell you what to return?

does the syncfusion documentation not tell you what to return? Unfortunately, no

Ok. I would expect that you should probably return the actual content of the image file which is requested. I expect the PHP script will receive from the client-side some sort of ID or path of the file it wants to be served to it. Try starting with a PHP script which just dumps out the request variables sent to it, so you can see what information it receives from the front-end

The library send a get request with this params:
page: getImage
path: Documents/Projets/9/
id: ../Documents/Projets/9/d9fwkjz-ef8e1e85-62b4-445d-8853-9815b3e5e0d5_66db087cb691e.png
time: 1725975676748

Ok. So I guess you should return the content of the image file which is associated with that ID / path

Your PHP code should return the binary content of the image file associated with the ID / path name passed to the php script from the frontend ajax code.
